# Will crowdsourcing impact the freelancer business in SW development? And how?

Tags: outsourcing

Looking at Outsourcing in SW development & maintenance (mainly given to large service providers) and the current trends in crowdsourcing (e.g. SW testing) I am keen to understand whether freelancers will be combined in a crowdsourcing set up (e.g. by 3rd parties) and used to enter the large scale SW Outsourcing game (crowdsourcing set up replacing larger Service Providers). Will customers and freelancers (individuals) go for that?

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more your question? I think I am not the only one who do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

I freelance full time and I avoid all crowd sourcing sites like the plague. They are bad for business here.

Working on "spec" is just bad practice for freelancers.

As to impact, it has none here. My clients are not and never will be the clients who settle for crowd sourcing services. There is a market for crowd sourcing, but it's just not the same market I pursue.